# Android - Using PreferenceScreen to display and save settings to/from ContentProvider

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, android-contentprovider, preference

I have my own custom Content Provider that loads a database which contains the settings information for my application.

I load the settings from the ContentProvider on the creation of my Settings activity.

My Settings activity is made up of a PreferenceScreen and Dialog based EditText's.

The following code shows how I use the preference screen and edit texts.

So as you can see from the first image this works and displays the menu with the information underneath.

The problem is in image two, when I click on a choice in the menu the dialog pops up but it is empty, I would like to be able to load the data from my content provider into the edit text in the dialog, so in image one it shows "Donal" as the user name so in image two "Donal" should also appear in the edit text in the dialog.

I would also like to be able to listen to the OK button in the dialog so when a user changes a setting I can update the data in my content provider.

Can anyone help me with what I'm trying to do?

---

**Code**

```
public class PreferencesApp extends PreferenceActivity {

String name;
EditTextListener etl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loadSettingsFromProvider();
    etl = new EditTextListener(this);

    setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
}

private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy() {
    // Root
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    // Dialog based preferences
    PreferenceCategory dialogBasedPrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    dialogBasedPrefCat.setTitle(R.string.dialog_based_preferences);
    root.addPreference(dialogBasedPrefCat);

    // Edit text preference
    EditTextPreference editTextPref = new EditTextPreference(this);
    editTextPref.setDialogTitle(R.string.dialog_title_edittext_preference);
    editTextPref.setKey("edittext_preference");
    editTextPref.setTitle(R.string.title_edittext_preference);
    editTextPref.setSummary(name);
    dialogBasedPrefCat.addPreference(editTextPref);


    return root;
}

public class EditTextListener extends EditTextPreference{

    public EditTextListener(Context context){

        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    //When the dialog is closed, perform the relevant actions
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {

        if (positiveResult) {
         String text=getEditText().getText().toString();
         Log.d("DIALOG CLOSED", "OK");
         }
        else {
         // cancel hit
         Log.d("DIALOG CLOSED", "CANCEL");
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup the available methods in the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html).
<strike>You can subscribe to `onDialogClosed` to get the OK or Cancel click event.</strike>

Also look into `getEditText` method that will return the edittext of the Dialog, and you can set the value there. Or even look into `setText`, you maybe can set the value with it. This later untested by me.

**EDIT 1**

Sorry, you can't subscribe. You have to subclass the `EditTextPreference`  and override the method. A complex example is [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/EditPhoneNumberPreference.java) but you don't need all the stuff You are interested in this:

```
@Override
//When the dialog is closed, perform the relevant actions
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {

    if (positiveResult) {
     String text=getEditText().getText().toString();
     }
    else {
     // cancel hit
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

You have to drop

```
etl = new EditTextListener(this);
```

You have to implement your new class

```
EditTextPreference editTextPref = new EditTextListener(this);
```

so the code will become

```
// Edit text preference
EditTextPreference editTextPref = new EditTextListener(this);
editTextPref.setDialogTitle(R.string.dialog_title_edittext_preference);
editTextPref.setKey("edittext_preference");
editTextPref.setTitle(R.string.title_edittext_preference);
editTextPref.setSummary(name);
dialogBasedPrefCat.addPreference(editTextPref);
```

Comment: Thanks Pentium, Can you explain how I subscribe to onDialogClosed?

Comment: Hi Pentium, Thanks for that, I'm nearly there I think, I have revised my code in my question to show you what I have now my class extends PreferenceActivity So I had to create a sub class called EditTextListener and have it extend EditTextPreference and implement the onDialogClosed method.     I then create a new EditTextListener (etl) and pass it the activity as a context. But it still doesn't work, Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: As I see from here, you need just a small change. See my 2nd edit.